# Sabre Event Notification Services Profile Subscription Payload Examples

Tags: xml, web-services, sabre

Is there any actual XML example available of the payloads for the Sabre Event Notification service for profile changes? The [examples given in the developer center](http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/ENS/ENS_v1_3_1/ENS_v1-3-1_SampleMessages.zip) are listed as being last updated almost 10 years ago and do not contain any payloads for the Profile service subscription.

Examples of a single notification and a batch notification would be ideal.

The developer documentation has fragments of payloads but nothing to write code against, and the example payload that gets sent to the endpoint to validate a good response sends the test payload in the format used for PNR subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to receive some payloads and I thought I'd drop them in here for anyone else trying to get this to work. Personal data has been removed from this, obviously.

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:swse="http://wse.sabre.com/eventing" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/eventing">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wse:MySubscription>IPCC</wse:MySubscription>
            <swse:EventTopic>WSE.QUEUE.PPP.PROFILECHNG</swse:EventTopic>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsa:Action>http://wse.sabre.com/EventSource/notification</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>asdgat23tt55-12g1-4522-eaa-97a0987g08970</wsa:MessageID>
        <wse:Identifer>45chytqte-154d-4706-a6ad-25225d25255</wse:Identifer>
        <wsa:To>https://www.yourwebapiendpoint.com/api/enslistener</wsa:To>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <swse:Sabre_OTA_EventNotification RequestTrackingID="GUID-GUID-GUID-GUID-GUIDGUID" TimeStamp="2021-02-19T22:35:27.137Z" xmlns="http://www.sabre.com/eps/schemas">
            <swse:ProfileEvent>
                <swse:Action Timestamp="2021-02-19T22:35:16.388Z" Type="UPDATE"/>
                <swse:TPA_Identity ClientCode="TN" ClientContextCode="CON" DomainID="IPCC" ProfileName="LASTNAME/PASSENGERNAME T" ProfileTypeCode="TVL" UniqueID="UNIQUEID"/>
                <swse:SubjectArea Name="PersonName" OrderSequenceNo="1"/>
                <swse:SubjectArea Name="PaymentForm" OrderSequenceNo="1"/>
                <swse:SubjectArea Name="Document" OrderSequenceNo="1"/>
                <swse:SubjectArea Name="EmploymentInfo" OrderSequenceNo="1"/>
                <swse:SubjectArea Name="CustomDefinedData" OrderSequenceNo="2"/>
                <swse:SubjectArea Name="AirlinePref" OrderSequenceNo="1">
                <swse:SubjectArea Name="AirlineSeatPref"/>
                </swse:SubjectArea>
            </swse:ProfileEvent>
        </swse:Sabre_OTA_EventNotification>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```